# Why is the user not updating? Am i passing the data correctly?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to allow a user to update their account details. So they fill in the form and hit submit. Here is the code:

Model:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_details($data)
{
$query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $data['id']));
return $query->row_array();

}



public function update_user($data)
{

$this->load->helper('url');

$data2 = array(
    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email')
    );

$this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
$this->db->update('users', $data2); 

}

}
```

My controller:

```
public function myaccount()
 {
 $this->load->helper('form');
 $this->load->helper('url');
 $this->load->model('myaccount_model');
 $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
 $config = array(
           array(
                 'field'   => 'username', 
                 'label'   => 'Username', 
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'password', 
                 'label'   => 'Password', 
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|matches[passconf]'
              ),
            array(
                 'field'   => 'passconf', 
                 'label'   => 'Password Confirmation', 
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required'
              ),
           array(
                 'field'   => 'email', 
                 'label'   => 'Email', 
                 'rules'   => 'trim|required|valid_email'
              )
        );
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Field required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);  
     if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))

   {
   if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
   {
   $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
   $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
   $data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);
   $this->load->view('head');
   $this->load->view('myaccount', $data);
   $this->load->view('footer');
   }
 else
 {
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
 $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
 $data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->update_user($data);
    redirect ('login', 'refresh');
 }
 } else
 {
 redirect('login', 'refresh');
 }
```

I don't think I'm passing the data (user id) correctly on this line:

```
$data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->update_user($data);
```

Everything works fine, however when the user clicks submit, the page refreshes and the users data is not updated.

Thanks !

Comment: Sidenote: Noticing the use of MD5 for password storage. It is old and considered broken. For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, both your queries (`get_details()` and `update_user()`) is wrong.

The `$data` is just an array, so you have to specify the id key as well.

These two

```
$data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->get_details($data);
...
$data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->update_user($data);
```

Should be

```
$data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->get_details($data['id']);
...
$data['result']=$this->myaccount_model->update_user($data['id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user id in the session may be incorrect. Make sure your data is correct at this line:

`$data['id'] = $session_data['id'];`

Try dumping out the $data and $data2 variables and verify that everything is correct before the update at:

`$this->db->update('users', $data2);`